# dimple.js change radius of circles

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I try to change the radius of the circles with class 'minima' in a bubble-plot from dimple.js. However, only stroke and opacity get updated, but not the size.

```
chart.draw();

d3.selectAll(".minima")
    .style("stroke", "#000000")  // works
    .attr("opacity", "0.2")      // works
    .attr("r", 25);              // doesn't work
```

I don't see, what I am doing wrong here.

Background-info: I want only the 'minima-circles' to be bigger than the others without declaring a z-axis for the size, because I don't want this size-values to appear in the tooltip / pop-up.

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Hmm, I can't answer this yet but I can shed some more light.  Dimple draws it's shapes using a 0ms transition which doesn't have a visible effect but which seems to interfere here.  If you use `d3.selectAll(".minima").transition().duration(0).attr("r", 25);` the radius change will work but for some reason it messes up the cx/cy values.  Presumably because they are set in the same transition as the radius.  You need some way to pick up the executing transition on the shape and tag this on the end.  Here's a simple example for anyone trying to solve it http://jsfiddle.net/T6ZDL/1/

Comment: @Lars Sorry, I was out for lunch. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following from my comment above, this works but isn't very robust:

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
var data = [
    { "Word":"Hello", "Awesomeness":2000 },
    { "Word":"World", "Awesomeness":3000 }
];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Word");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Awesomeness");
var s = chart.addSeries("Word", dimple.plot.bubble);
chart.draw();

setTimeout(function () {
     svg.selectAll("circle.Hello")
        .attr("opacity", 0.2)
        .attr("r", 100);
}, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T6ZDL/4/

Comment: Just been trying to solve the same problem. It's a pity there's apparently no way of adding a callback to `.draw` once it's rendered?

Comment: This is no longer a problem in version 2 (http://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/releases/tag/2.0.0) so your original code will now work.  Also a callback has now been added to allow methods to run after drawing (e.g. http://dimplejs.org/adhoc_viewer.html?id=adhoc_bar_labels)