# DimpleJS overrideMax, Dates and series drawing order

Tags: dimple.js

I have this interactive chart [here](http://www.fedea.net/pymes-morosidad/). As its data change depending on selected time period I wish to set the date range from Nov-10 to Jul-14, no matter the data. I know that I must use overrideMax on x axis, but I can't make it to work. I guess it's a matter of date formatting. Every single combination I've tried gives the following as result.[image: result]

What is the right formatting? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Thank you very much on your quick response, John. Now it is working. I'm loving Dimple more and more!

I have another question regarding this chart. Is there any way to arrange drawing order of series? I would like 'Previsión' to be sent to back. Now it is drawn depending on time period.

[image: 'Previsión' on back]
[image: 'Previsión' at the front]

EDIT 2: Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836594/dimple-js-change-radius-of-circles) other question I think I figured out a solution. With a 50ms delay after the chart is drawn I simple erase the circles and paths I wish to be at the front and then append them to the chart svg object.

```
setTimeout(function () {
        var datoCircles = svg.selectAll('circle[id*=Dato]:not([id*=futuro])');
        var prevCircles = svg.selectAll('circle[id*=Prev]');
        var prevPaths = svg.selectAll('path[class*=Prev]');

        datoCircles.remove();
        prevCircles.remove();
        prevPaths.remove();

        // Convertimos la seleción d3 a objetos jQuery
        $(svg.selectAll('svg > g')[0])
            .append($(prevPaths[0]))
            .append($(prevCircles[0]))
            .append($(datoCircles[0]));

    }, 50);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to be set with JavaScript date objects, as native date parsing in JavaScript causes cross browser problems, I recommend using the d3 method:

```
x.overrideMax = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse("2014-05-09");
```

With this approach you can use whichever date format suits you.

Comment: By the way, I see you're using version 1.1.5.  Version 2 is now out which fixes many things, including x axis formatting when y doesn't start at zero.  More details here (https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/releases/tag/2.0.0)